# Expect-respond doesn't work in AngularJS unit testing(Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, getjson

My aim is to load data to the html via pre-set response of the AngularJS mocking service(jasmine). The data.json is also there, so if the mock response doesn't work the words displayed would be "http" instead of "mock". But the response turns out always be "http" which means the mock service doesn't really work. 
Very much thankful for any ideas about the issue.

Jasmine javascript file:

```
describe("DController", function() {
var httpBackend,scope;
beforeEach(module('MyApp'));    

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$httpBackend,$http,$controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    DController = $controller('DController', {
            $scope: scope
    });
    httpBackend.expectGET('data.json').respond({
        "name": "mock"
    });
})); })
```

controller.js file

```
.controller('DController',function($scope,$http) {'use strict';

$scope.loadJson = function() { 
    var getDataJson = $http.get('data.json');

    getDataJson.success(function(data, status, headers, config)  {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}})
```

and data.json is simply

```
{   "name": "http"  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "whenGET" instead of "expectGET"?